# My view on Web2Py shows "none" though I have html?

Tags: python, web2py, web2py-modules

This is the html code I have for in my Web2Py view file:

```
    {{extend 'layout.html'}}
    <h1>This is the profile/view.html template</h1>
```

However, I am only seeing "none" printed on the view page when I run it. How should I resolve this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check the controller to see if you are returning any variables.